# Group Timestamps in array into unique instances and count them via php

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var_dump($Burner_Control_Alm);
```

```
array(5642) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:04:48" 
    [1]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:04:54" 
    [2]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:00" 
    [3]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:06" 
    [4]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:12" 
    [5]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:18" 
    [6]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:06:18" 
    [7]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:06:24"
}
```

How can I group / count instances in the array that continue a six second count in time, so 0 ==> 5 counts as one instance. and 6 ==> 7 count as 1 instance.

When there is more than a six second gap in the time stamp it should start the new instance and end when the next out of sequence timestamp happens.

I am using PHP.

I'm currently only showing all instances but we need unique instances

[image]

```
        $burner_time = array();
            foreach($Burner_Control_Alm as $new_burner){
            $burner_time[] = strtotime($new_burner);            
            }


        $repl = 'end';
        for ($i=1; $i<count($burner_time); $i++) {
            $value_second = $burner_time[$i];
            $value_first = $burner_time[$i-1] === $repl ? $burner_time[$i-2] : 
        $burner_time[$i-1];
            if ($value_second > $value_first + 6) {
                array_splice($burner_time, $i++, 0, $repl);
            }
            print_r($burner_time);
        }
```

This outputs like below but in epoch strings. Id much rather group by arrays instead of adding a element between gaps.

```
array(5642) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:04:48" 
    [1]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:04:54" 
    [2]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:00" 
    [3]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:06" 
    [4]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:12" 
    [5]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:05:18" 
    [6]=> string(19) "end"
    [6]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:06:18" 
    [7]=> string(19) "2021-02-10 09:06:24"
}
```

Comment: You can do this with a simple loop, using `DateTime` objects for comparison. Have you tried anything? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to try and reach the solution on your own. If you've tried something, please share the code and explain where and how it fails to do what you need.

Comment: Honestly im all over the place trying to group with DateTime Objects. That's why I posted, but I completely understand your end. Ill work some stuff back up and give you a response soon. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: @El_Vanja Any advice would be great. Thanks again